# Posting MP4 Videos to Instagram always returns error code 2207026

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I posted an MP4 Video to instagram using the Facebook Graph API for Content Publishing with the below code, but for most of the time I'm getting back the error occurred `2207026` while checking the status of the video.

The code is below:

```
let mediaContainerUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com/${igUserId}/media`;
let videoURL = `URL Of MP4 Video Hosted on Firebase Storage`;
let containerParams = new URLSearchParams();
containerParams.append('caption', body);
containerParams.append('video_url', videoURL);
containerParams.append('access_token', targetAccessToken);
let mediaContainerResponse = await axios.post(mediaContainerUrl, containerParams);
let { id: mediaContainerId } = mediaContainerResponse.data; //Upload is done here
```

I now checked the status of the uploaded video using the below code:

```
let mediaContainerStatusEndpoint = `https://graph.facebook.com/${mediaContainerId}?fields=status_code,status&access_token=${targetAccessToken}`;
let { data: mediaContainerStatus } = await axios.get(mediaContainerStatusEndpoint);
let { status_code, status } = mediaContainerStatus; //Unfortunately, status is most times coming back as `2207026` even for valid videos
```

So, is there a reason I keep getting back the status code `2207026`? Because status code `2207026` means invalid video format. But the video format seems valid to me

Please note that the video is an MP4 and also under 60seconds.

Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: MP4 is a container format and not a video format. MP4 containers can contain a huge amount of different video formats.

Comment: Did you manage to do it?
Did you find a nice way to do this?

Comment: Really interesting what you're saying @WizKid . Indeed, when I run `ffprobe` on my `.mp4`-ending video file, I get :
`codec_name: 'h264'`
`codec_long_name: 'H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10'`
In Instagram docs, they ask **MPEG-4 part 14**, do you think it is this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**What is the aspect ratio of the video you're trying to post?**

I got the same error when I tried posting `1024x490` video which is above `1.91/1` (max) aspect ratio.

Instagram, at the moment of writing this answer, allows aspect ratio within a range of `4:5 - 1.91:1`

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media/

****Late answer but might be helpful to others.*